# back button in cordova/phongap meteor build for android won't close application consistently

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I've built and app for android with meteor and phonegap/cordova:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idqkd3gsl4qt51152xgy

It works decently OK (especially given that I'm not really a programmer), but one UX issue I've been struggling with is that the app will not consistently close when pressing the back button on my phone. Every once in a while it works on the first press, but most of the time I have to jam it 5-6 times in a row to get the app to close.

I'm using the latest iron-router. The rest of the packages I'm using don't seem particularly relevant to this issue but they are as follows just in case:

standard-app-packages
coffeescript
natestrauser:font-awesome@4.1.0
accounts-password
aldeed:autoform
aldeed:collection2
nemo64:bootstrap
less
alanning:roles
joshowens:accounts-entry
mrt:accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3
mizzao:jquery-ui
iron:router
sacha:spin
raix:push
mizzao:bootboxjs
meteorhacks:kadira
bootstrap3-media-query

the repo can be seen here: https://github.com/The3vilMonkey/BrewsOnTap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't specify the exact reason for this issue other than it seems like at startup there is a sort of redirect happening with cordova apps. Best solution I've found is to catch the popstate event and when you get back to the beginning exit or suspend the application.. I prefer suspend that way when the user comes back to the app it doesn't start it's lifecycle from the beginning.

```
if(Meteor.isCordova){
    Meteor.startup(function(){
        window.onpopstate = function () {
            if (history.state && history.state.initial === true){
                navigator.app.exitApp();

                //or to suspend meteor add cordova:org.android.tools.suspend@0.1.2
                //window.plugins.Suspend.suspendApp();
            }
        };
    });
}
```

One caveat that got me when I first used this was redirecting to a login page if the user wasn't logged in.. If you're using this method in an app that does this, you'll want to switch to rendering the login page in place rather than redirecting otherwise your app will exit/suspend immediately.

Comment: i don't know this is the answer for my specific issue yet (will update when I do) but this answer certainly satisfies the general question I asked so I've marked it correct

Comment: added the solution that worked for me below. Would love if you could take a glance and see if there are any obvious issues I'm not seeing. Awarded the 50 points to you nonetheless

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I made a mix of the two previous answers so that it works well.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){
  if (history.state && history.state.initial === true) {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
  } else {
    history.go(-1);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

While Kelly's answer does work, it did not end up being functionally correct for my particular situation. An important point to note about that solution is that it will exit as soon as the back button causes you to return to the initial page and not when you press the back button while on the initial page.

Ultimately I used cordova's backbutton listener to see if the backbutton was pressed:

```
if Meteor.isCordova
    Meteor.startup ->
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", ->
            if document.location.pathname is "/"
                navigator.app.exitApp()
            else
                history.go(-1)
```

and then if I am at the root of my application I exit/suspend, otherwise I simply go back in the history.

Using the backbutton event listener does seem to override it's default functionality so calling history.go(-1) was necessary in my case.

Also note that this solution would break if you want a true history that could go back through the history (potentially hitting the root of your application multiple times) before existing on the initial entry point. A combination of my answer and Kelly's might work for that. I find that while that might be the expected behavior for websites, it isn't really for mobile apps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a meteor package available to do this for you as well:

https://github.com/remcoder/fix-back-button-android

**EDIT:**
I actually went ahead and forked that repo, fixed the cordova plugin dependency issues, and used Kelly's code instead of the code from the original repo, find my fork here:
https://github.com/tripflex/fix-back-button-android

Or install in Meteor using:

```
meteor add tripflex:fix-back-button-android
```

I can confirm it works correctly, when adding via GitHub method described below, and using Kelly's answer for detecting the root page (do not use the example on the GitHub repo).

I'm no meteor expert as well (but am a full time dev), but going off of Kelly's answer, I would move the check for `isCordova` inside the Meteor Startup (as i'm sure you will have more startup code as your app progresses)

```
Meteor.startup(function(){

    // Mobile specific code
    if(Meteor.isCordova) {

        window.onpopstate = function () {
            if (history.state && history.state.initial === true) {
                navigator.app.exitApp();

                //or to suspend meteor add cordova:org.android.tools.suspend@0.1.2
                //window.plugins.Suspend.suspendApp();
            }
        };

    }

   // Any other startup code below here
});
```

EDIT: If you decide you want to use the cordova suspend package, **it will not work like most cordova plugins in Meteor** due to the plugin not existing in npm, ***so this will NOT work:***

```
meteor add cordova:org.android.tools.suspend@0.1.2
```

**You MUST add it like this using the GitHub repo:**

```
meteor add cordova:org.android.tools.suspend@https://github.com/Lamerchun/org.android.tools.suspend.git#0dbb52cca0244ba22a8c7975895f0f45d2e9a4a9
```